# limit $\lim_{x\to0} \frac{x^2}{\ln\left(\int^{\sqrt[3]{x^2}}_0e^{\frac{1}{2}x^2}dx+1-x^{2/3}\right)}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

The expression is:
$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{x^2}{\ln\left(\int^{\sqrt[3]{x^2}}_0e^{\frac{1}{2}x^2}dx+1-x^{2/3}\right)}$$

MATLAB says the result is $6$.

My first question is that, in someone's own solution I saw, he literally replaced the denominator by $\left(\int^{\sqrt[3]{x^2}}_0e^{\frac{1}{2}x^2}dx-x^{2/3}\right)$ in the very first step. Is it legitimate? I don't think so. It looks so wrong that I can't imagine it is true unless it is a clever theorem.

My second question is about how to compute $\frac{d}{dx}\int^{\sqrt[3]{x^2}}_0e^{\frac{1}{2}x^2}dx$. It seems this step is inevitable. I can't relate this to fundamental theorem of calculus. Is it simply $e^{\frac{1}{2}x^2}\cdot\frac{2}{3}x^{-1/3}$?

A full solution to this expression is also appreciated.

Comment: L'Hôpital's rule may work here

Comment: You are right about the derivative of $\int_0^{\sqrt[3] {x^2}} e^{\frac 1 2 t^2} dt$. Also, note that it is not a good idea to name the integration variable the same as another variable in the formula.

Comment: @AsafHaas No it is not $dt$, it is $dx$.

Comment: Regardless of what the expression you were given says, it is indeed bad form for a limit of integration (in this case $\sqrt[3]{x^2}$) to depend on the variable of integration ($x$).  It really should be $e^{\frac12t^2} \, dt$ to be technically correct, depending on what the intent really is.

Comment: @MonkeyKing As I said, this is exactly the confusion you get when you name the integration variable poorly. If the $x$ in $e^{\frac 1 2 x^2}$ is from the limit, then your differentiation is indeed false, but then $e^{\frac 1 2 x^2}$ is just a constant as far as the integral is aware of, and it would be rather strange and easy to evaluate. So I assumed this $x$ is the integration variable, and then there is nothing wrong with renaming it to $t$.

Comment: Ok I see, I thought there is a different meaning to integrating w.r.t. a dummy variable.

Comment: So why not edit it then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set
$$
F(x)=\int_0^{x}e^{t^2/2}\,dt
$$
(using the same variable is possible, but makes the thing less clear). Then your limit can be written as
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+} \frac{x^2}{\ln\left(F(x^{2/3})+1-x^{2/3}\right)}
$$
(just one sided, because the function is even).

Now set $u=x^{2/3}$, so $x=u^{3/2}$ and $x^2=u^3$, so the limit becomes
$$
\lim_{u\to0^+}\frac{u^3}{\ln(F(u)+1-u)}=
\lim_{u\to0^+}\frac{u^3}{F(u)-u}\frac{F(u)-u}{\ln(F(u)+1-u)}
$$
The second fraction has limit $1$ (why?), so we can disregard it and apply l’Hôpital (and the fundamental theorem of calculus):
$$
\lim_{u\to0^+}\frac{3u^2}{e^{u^2/2}-1}=
\lim_{u\to0^+}\frac{6u}{ue^{u^2/2}}=6
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hints: 1. $[\ln (1+u)]/u\to \ln'(1) = 1$ as $u\to 0.$ So your colleague is right, the denominator can be replaced by

$$\int_0^{x^{2/3}}e^{t^2/2}\,dt - x^{2/3}.$$

2. $e^{t^2/2} = 1 + t^2/2 +O(t^4)$ as $t\to 0.$